# Forcing https in Grails

Tags: grails, https, filter

in a struts application, I have a filter that forces certain pages to be accessed only over https via redirection. I'm thinking in porting it to grails so my question is: In the this environment, is there a "grails" way to implement such filter or is it similar/the same as I did ? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Spring Security core plugin](http://grails.org/plugins/spring-security-core) has support for this. See section 17 - ["Channel security"](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#channelSecurity)

Comment: In version 1.1.2 documentation this is now in section 17 still titled Channel Security.

Comment: Updated deadlink -- now points to section 17 in the latest (v3.x) documentation